# Pretty listing removes continuation character (_) -> error BC30201 in compiler [Visual Studio 2019]

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, underscore.js

I wanted to ask if you have a better solution for my problem:

When I enable "Pretty Listing" in Visual Studio 2019 or 2017 it removes all the continuation characters / underscores (_) at the end of rows that continue in the next row.

Visual Studio does not show an error, but once I try to compile the project the compiler (MS FW 3.5) returns an error BC30201 in that specific row.

I would like to keep Pretty Listing, since all the other fixes are useful. Is there a way to enable all Pretty Listing features except the removal of the continuation characters??

Thanks in advance for any useful response!!

Comment: Targeting 3.5 is getting to be pretty unpractical.  You'll need to compile with at least vb version 10.0 so the underscores become optional, [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Comment: Thank you, I tried to change the LangVersion in my .vbproj file to 10 and also to latest but in both cases the error occurs. That does not seem to solve my problem. :-( Thank you anyway!!

Comment: How do you solve this issue? Don't you target Framework 3.5 anymore? Or do you disable Pretty listing?

Comment: Any other possible solutions?